# how to differentiate database datasource properties in project structure for DIT UAT SIT and PROD in General (Spring framework)

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

how to differentiate datasource properties in project structure for DIT UAT SIT and prod in general or for spring framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently use Maven as our build and configuration tool.  We keep environment specific properties, such as, database URLs, usernames, passwords, etc. in Maven profiles.  Maven resource filtering is applied to Spring configuration files to inject environment specific properties.

In the past when I used Ant for building applications, I used to store environment specific properties in separate properties files.  Then, Ant token replacement was applied to inject environment specific properties.

Comment: i like the way you proposed, but i think with this approach every one can be able to see the Username/Password of the database connection for all the environment including production.

Comment: Of course we do not store any passwords in plain text in the files.  These are always stored encrypted, such that they can only be decrypted on the environment and not by developers on their machines.  You can use other strategies for passwords as well - not storing them in source control but injecting them through scripts directly on the servers.

Comment: Ok will try to implement and test it. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.